# How to use Django-hitcount package to build a view count

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am learning Django and came across this Django package called 'Django-hitcount'. But I don't know how to use it in my count. I want to display the number of times that an object is viewed

Below is my views.py

```
def home(request):
    songs = Songs.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'explore/home.html', {'songs': songs})
    count_hit = True
```

This is my models.py

```
class Songs(models.Model, HitCountMixin):
    ...
    plays = GenericRelation(HitCount, object_id_field='object_pk', related_query_name='hit_count_generic_relation')
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-updated']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.song_title
```

And my html file
        ...

```
    <p><strong><h5>{{ song.song_title }}</h5></strong></p>
    <p><h5>{{ song.artist }}</h5></p>
    <span>plays: {% get_hit_count for [song] %}</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up different ways of counting the hits and displaying the hit counts.

First of all, to count the number of hits for one object, you'll need to add a DetailView, which shows one single song. This class is also where you add the `count_hit` parameter Something like this (views.py):

```
from hitcount.views import HitCountDetailView

class SongDetailView(HitCountDetailView):
    model = Song        
    count_hit = True    
    template = 'song_detail.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
        return redirect(self.object.song.audio_file.url)
```

`HitCountDetailView` is hitcount's built in view that gets a single object and adds up the hitcounts.

Add a template to display a single song (song_detail.html):

```
<p><strong><h5>{{ object.song_title }}</h5></strong></p>
<p><h5>{{ object.artist }}</h5></p>
<span>plays: {% get_hit_count for [object] %}</span>
```

Then in your urls add the following pattern (urls.py):

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('song/<int:id>/', SongDetailView.as_view(), name='song-detail'),
    ...
]
```

You now have two urls, one that leads to home, and one that leads to song/, the first should display a list of songs, the second just one song.

There is some unnecessary/wrong code in your original code, which I will explain below:

Your models.py has a generic relation, to HitCount, which is not necessary, unless you want to do some direct lookups to this models HitCount, but for now, you can leave it out.

The `HitCountMixin` should be added to a view, specifically a class based view, but not to a model. You models.py should look like this:

```
class Songs(models.Model):
    ...
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-updated']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.song_title
```

Your template looks like it's part of a file, but if it's not, it's not correct. Better would be to loop over each song (You can also link to your new detail-view), like this:

```
{% for song in songs %}
    <p><strong><h5>{{ song.song_title }}</h5></strong></p>
    <p><h5>{{ song.artist }}</h5></p>
    <span>plays: {% get_hit_count for [song] %}</span>
    <a href="{% url 'song-detail' song.id %}">Play song</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Actually, I don't want to have any details page for the song. The song "thumbnail" image will have the following link {{ song.song.audio_file.url }}. So can I still display the number of hits in the home.html

Comment: Nope, hit-count is for showing the number of page views for a detail view, it won't be able to take note of the number of times a file in the song model was downloaded.

Comment: Really. Any alternative to hitcount?

Comment: I've looked into the source for HitCountDetailView, and by updating the get method of the SongDetailView, you can update the hitcount, and then redirect to the file url. I have updated my answer accordingly.

As long as a file is downloaded through song/<id>, it will count towards its hit-count

Comment: After the code you suggested, I got an error saying (Reverse for 'song_detail' not found. 'song_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.)

Comment: I also need help, It is working fine, I'm it display hit counts only in the detail page but i also want to display hit count on the list page

Comment: @Sammy, make sure you use ‘song-detail’, not ‘song_detail’.

Comment: @Sandeep Did you add ‘{% get_hit_count for [song] %}’ to your list page?

Comment: @Nico Griffioen, I still get an error saying **Reverse for 'song-detail' not found. 'song-detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.**